# Can I avoid using union all statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I've got an extract out of a system that shows the data in excel in the following format:

[image: Like this]

I've used lengthy union statement to get to the following outcome:

[image: Like this]

I'm wondering is there a better way that's less messy and easier to read over than a whole bunch of union all statements?

Comment: you can use left join or right join

Comment: Given the output you desire, you need to look up the definition of PIVOT and UNPIVOT. Of course, the implementation depends upon your RDBMS but the concept is the same. I suspect that you'll get more answers once you correctly tag your question with your chosen RDBMS vendor. Either that or someone will indicate your question is already answered elsewhere.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with `SQL Server` then *cross apply* would be better approach then `UNION ALL` statement

```
select a.* from table t
cross apply (
       values (PersonId, 'Q1', Q1)
             ,(PersonId, 'Q2', Q2)
             ,(PersonId, 'Q3', Q3)
             ,(PersonId, 'Q4', Q4)
               ...
               ...
             ,(PersonId, 'Q20', Q20)
)a(PersonId, Q, Outcome)
order by a.Q, a.PersonId
```

Comment: The only problem is I have thousands of personID's and only 20 questions

Comment: @NS01.. no metter how much the person id you have.

Comment: `cross apply` is non-standard SQL and currently the question is only tagged with `sql` not with a specific database product.

Comment: Thats worked great! Thank you! What if I want to reference another table that has further questions and answers?

Comment: @NS01... However, if you want to reference the other table then you should join them and reference the `PersonId`.. with  further question for more you could edit the question or ask other. cause it would be hard to tell without clear road map or what exactly you want.